# Why am I getting a "read only" error here? an imported variable is read-only?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I get the following error and cannot seem to find where this error is produced. I just did a site conversion to JSX.

**ERROR:**

> ./src/containers/Services.js Syntax error:
>   C:/Users/me/Desktop/backups/react-static/site/src/containers/Services.js:
>   "timerId" is read-only

```
    <div
        id="sliderNext"
        onClick={() => {
          nextSlide();
          clearTimeout(timerId);
          setTimeout(function tick() {
            nextSlide();
            timerId = setTimeout(tick, 7000); 
          }, 7000); 
         }}
    >
```

**My code.js:**

```
export var timerId = () => {
        setTimeout(function tick() {
            nextSlide();
            timerId = setTimeout(tick, 7000); 
        }, 7000);
    };
```

Comment: Try changing the variable name or the method. I think you are having a collision of var names.

Comment: `timerId` is first an arrow function, next a setTimeout id, so you basically use the same name for two different things, not a good idea ;)